# Getter/setter in constructor

Tags: javascript, prototype, constructor, getter-setter

I recently read about the fact that there is a possibility of defining getters/setters in JavaScript. It seems extremely helpful - the setter is a kind of 'helper' which can parse the value to be set first, before actually setting it.

For example, I currently have this code:

```
var obj = function(value) {
    var test = !!value; // 'test' has to be a boolean
    return {
        get test() { return test },
        set test(value) { test = !!value }
    };
};

var instance = new obj(true);
```

This code always converts `value` to a boolean. So if you code `instance.test = 0`, then `instance.test === false`.

However, for this to work you have to actually return an **object**, which means that the new instance is not of type `obj` but just is a plain object. This means that changing the prototype of `obj` has no effect on instances. For example, this does **not** work - `instance.func` is undefined:

```
obj.prototype.func = function() { console.log(this.value); };
```

because `instance` is not of type `obj`. To get the prototype functions work, I guess I should not return a plain object, but rather not return anything so that `instance` would just be of type `obj`, like a regular constructor works.

The problem then is how to implement getters/setters? I can only find articles describing how to add these to an object, not as being part of the constructor of a custom type.

So how do I implement getters/setters in the constructor so as to be able to both use getters/setters and extending the prototype?

Comment: @Pointy watch out with those thing. Yes there slower but I doubt it can cause a notable bottleneck in almost all cases.

Comment: Thanks for that article. I haven't experienced any performance breakdowns though.

Comment: @Pointy That link is dead now, could you provide an alternative? Curious what it entails.

Comment: @ApathyBear darn it, it was dumb to use a link shortener for that. I think it was something about runtime performance. Somebody asked a question with a jsperf about why getter/setter functions are so slow just recently (they're not *that* slow, just slower than you'd think they'd be).

Comment: @Pointy Link is broken :-)

Comment: @RoyiNamir yes, I know; it's been dead for a while and I wasn't able to locate it again. Sorry about that. (Since I posted the comment in 2011, whatever the article said it's probably irrelevant now because that's such a long time ago in the JavaScript world.)

Comment: @Pointy Here's an archive of the dead link from the Internet Archives: https://web.archive.org/web/20110310163319/http://labs.transloc.com/?p=21

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can't do that.

You can set setter/getters for properties of objects though. I advice you use ES5 [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) though. of course this only works in modern browsers.

```
var obj = function() {
    ...
    Object.defineProperties(this, {
        "test": {
             "get": function() { ... },
             "set": function() { ... }
        }
    });
}

obj.prototype.func = function() { ... }

var o = new obj;
o.test;
o.func();
```

Comment: This works great. It's a little more typing though, but a clear solution nevertheless.

Comment: This is great. I wish the syntax was a little cleaner but it works. I kind of wish you could do `this.myProp = get () { }` like you can with normal functions.

Comment: Wouldn't this create get/set functions every time you do new obj ?

Answer (score 20):

Usually you want *class* methods.  The answer by @Raynos on May 7, 2011 gets the job done, but it defines an *instance* method, not a class method.

The following illustrates a class definition with a the getter and setter being part of the class.  This definition is a lot like the answer by @Raynos, but with two differences in the code: (1) The "defineProperties()" action has been moved out of the constructor. (2) The argument to "defineProperties()"as been changed from the instance object "this", to the constructor's prototype object.

```
function TheConstructor(side) {
  this.side = side;
}

Object.defineProperties(TheConstructor.prototype, {
        area: {
             get: function()    { return this.side * this.side; }
            ,set: function(val) { this.side = Math.sqrt(val);   }
        }
});

// Test code:

var anInstance = new TheConstructor(2);
console.log("initial  Area:"+anInstance.area);
anInstance.area = 9;
console.log("modified Area:"+anInstance.area);
```

Which produces these results:

```
initial  Area:4
modified Area:9
```

Although usually the distinction between class versus instance
definition is just a matter of style, there is a purpose to 
good style, and there is a case where the distinction matters:
the *memoized getter*.  The purpose for a memoized getter is 
described here: [Smart/self-overwriting/lazy getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

Define the getter at the class level when the memoized value is to 
pertain to the entire class.  For example, a configuration file 
should be read only once; the resulting values should then apply 
for the duration of the program.  The following sample code 
defines a memoized getter at the class level.

```
function configureMe() {
  return 42;
}

Object.defineProperties(TheConstructor.prototype, {
    memoizedConfigParam: {
        get: function() {
            delete TheConstructor.prototype.memoizedConfigParam;
            return TheConstructor.prototype.memoizedConfigParam = configureMe();
        }
        ,configurable:  true
    }
});

// Test code:

console.log("memoizedConfigParam:"+anInstance.memoizedConfigParam);
```

Produces:

```
memoizedConfigParam:42
```

As can be seen in the example, memoized getters have the 
characteristic that the getter function deletes itself, 
then replaces itself with a simple value that 
(presumably) will never change.
Note that 'configurable' must be set to 'true'.

Define the getter at the instance level when the memoized value 
depends upon the contents of instance.  The definition moves 
inside the constructor, and the object of attention is 'this'.

```
function TheConstructorI(side) {

  this.side = side;

  Object.defineProperties(this, {
    memoizedCalculation: {
        get: function() {
            delete this.memoizedCalculation;
            return this.memoizedCalculation = this.expensiveOperation();
        }
        ,configurable:  true
    }
  });
}

TheConstructorI.prototype.expensiveOperation = function() {
  return this.side * this.side * this.side;
}

//Test code:

var instance2 = new TheConstructorI(2);
var instance3 = new TheConstructorI(3);

console.log("memoizedCalculation 2:"+instance2.memoizedCalculation);
console.log("memoizedCalculation 3:"+instance3.memoizedCalculation);
```

Produces:

```
memoizedCalculation 2:8
memoizedCalculation 3:27
```

If you want to guarantee (rather than presume) that the memoized
value will never be changed, the 'writable' attribute needs to 
be changed.  That makes the code a bit more complicated.

```
function TheConstructorJ(side) {

  this.side = side;

  Object.defineProperties(this, {
    memoizedCalculation: {
        get: function() {
            delete this.memoizedCalculation;
            Object.defineProperty( this, 'memoizedCalculation'
              ,{  value    : this.expensiveOperation()
                 ,writable : false
              });
            return this.memoizedCalculation;
        }
        ,configurable:  true
    }
  });
}

TheConstructorJ.prototype.expensiveOperation = function() {
  return this.side * this.side * this.side;
}

//Test code:

var instanceJ = new TheConstructorJ(2);

console.log("memoizedCalculation:"+instanceJ.memoizedCalculation);
instanceJ.memoizedCalculation = 42;  // results in error
```

Produces:

```
memoizedCalculation:8
>Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'memoizedCalculation' of object '#<TheConstructorJ>'
```

The OP's original question, from March 7, 2011, presented basic
getter and setter syntax, noted that it worked on an object but
not on 'this', and asked how to define getters and setters within
a constructor.  In addition to all the examples above, there is 
also a "cheap-shot" way of doing it: create a new object within
the constructor, like the OP did, but then assign the object to 
be a member within 'this'.  So, the original code would look like
this:

```
var MyClass = function(value) {
    var test = !!value; // 'test' has to be a boolean
    this.data = {
        get test() { return test },
        set test(value) { test = !!value }
    };
};

var instance = new MyClass(true);

// But now 'data' is part of the access path
instance.data.test = 0;
console.log(instance.data.test);
```

Produces:

```
false
```

Believe it or not, I have actually run into situations where 
this "cheap-shot" is the best solution.  Specifically, I used this
technique when I had records from several tables encapsulated within
a single class, and wanted to present a unified view as though 
they were a single record called 'data'.

Have fun.

IAM_AL_X

Answer (score 9):

Update for ES6 -- have a look at section 19.3.1 of Alex Rauschmayer's book *Exploring ES6* http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_maps-sets.html#sec_weakmaps-private-data which demonstrates how to use WeakMaps with getters and setters to hold private data.  Combining with section 16.2.2.3 http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_classes.html#leanpub-auto-getters-and-setters would result in something like

```
# module test_WeakMap_getter.js
var _MyClassProp = new WeakMap();
class MyClass {
    get prop() {
        return _MyClassProp.get( this ); 
    }
    set prop(value) {
        _MyClassProp.set( this, value );
    }
}
var mc = new MyClass();
mc.prop = 5 ;
console.log( 'My value is', mc.prop );

$ node --use_strict test_WeakMap_getter.js 
My value is 5
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function Obj(value){
    this.value = !!value;
}

Obj.prototype = {
    get test () {
        return this.value;``
    },
    set test (value) {
        this.value = !!this.value;
    }
};
var obj = new Obj(true);
```

Comment: Please add a description of what your code is doing to help the OP understand it better.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When posting answers, it is important to explain your code and explain how one might use it

Comment: Funny, I scrolled all of the top answers because the text explaining the code is utterly a waste of time in this case, your code explains itself, and is exactly what the OP probably wish he used. Thanks.

Comment: Not a good practice to replace your prototype by default the obj.prototype would have a property constructor that would be pointing back to Obj. You would need to add that if you are using instanceOf to check if the objects created with Obj are its instances. More over that would be very explicit and there ought to be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this might be extremely late but I figured out a different way to accomplish what you want and for the sake of people, like myself, googling for an answer to this here it is.

```
function Constructor(input){
     this.input = input;
}
Object.__defineGetter__.call(Constructor.prototype, "value", function(){
    return this.input * 2;
});

var test = new Constructor(5);
alert(test.value) // 10
```

I've tested this in chrome, safari, mobile safari, firefox and they all work (latest versions of course)

Comment: I'm not sure this works cross-browser, but even if it does it's really gross looking. Is there any reason why you would go this route instead of using `defineProperties()` as @Raynos did?

Comment: Fair warning, this syntax is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineGetter__). Going forward for modern browsers the appropriate syntax is `Object.defineProperty(someObject, 'somePropertyName', { get: function(){}, set: function(val){} })`.

Answer (score 1):

@Alex I see it as more option and more power, programming is art, @Nat share his finding with us, and for that I thank him. Maybe someone want to do it that way.

I'm sure the setter version is the same but just changing that g to a s.

i.g:

```
function Constructor(input){
     this.input = input;
}

Object.__defineGetter__.call(Constructor.prototype, "value", function(){
    return this.input * 2;
});

Object.__defineSetter__.call(Constructor.prototype, "bar", function(foo){
    return this.input *= foo;
});

var test = new Constructor(5);
console.log(test.value); // 10
test.bar = 5;
console.log(test.input); //25
```

With that said, this feature is deprecated, advices to not to use in production coding.