# Can I create a javascript function in EcmaScript 5 with the new get and set in one declaration?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-5

I am very interested in ES5 getters and setters for use as Angular.js controllers. Currently I am doing:

```
var helloEC5 = function(){
  //constructor
  this.pants = "jeans";
};
helloEC5.prototype = {
    firstName: 'Seeya',
    lastName: 'Latir',
    get fullName() {
      console.log("get")
        return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    },
    set fullName (name) {
      console.log('set')
        var words = name.toString().split(' ');
        this.firstName = words[0] || '';
        this.lastName = words[1] || '';
    }
};
```

But is there any way to do this in the function() succinctly together? What I really want is (pseudo code) ;

```
var helloEC5 = function() {
    firstName: 'Seeya',
    lastName: 'Latir',
    get fullName() {
      console.log("get")
        return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    },
    set fullName (name) {
      console.log('set')
        var words = name.toString().split(' ');
        this.firstName = words[0] || '';
        this.lastName = words[1] || '';
    }
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getter/setter in constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222209/getter-setter-in-constructor)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with the [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) method (http://jsfiddle.net/ydhLbwg6/):

```
var helloEC5 = function () {
    this.firstName = 'Seeya';
    this.lastName = 'Latir';
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'fullName', {
        get: function () {
            console.log('get');
            return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            console.log('set');
            var words = value.toString().split(' ');
            this.firstName = words[0] || '';
            this.lastName = words[1] || '';
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Too wordy for me, I wonder if https://github.com/Baqend/jahcode is a good compromise between brevity and native goodness?

Comment: Where is the constructor on that? Is there any standard way to mixin constructor arguments as properties?