# Saving a property and having a getter at the same time

Tags: javascript, class

I am trying to have a private property inside my class. I have a class called `Person` and an instance of that class: `person` declared with `let person = new Person('name1')`.

I would like to save the name in `person`'s properties. I could simply do:

```
class Person {

  constructor(name) {

    this.name = name;

  }

}
```

But I also want to perform some actions when changing this value, so I use a Setter:

```
class Person {

  set name() {

    // some actions 

  }

  constructor(name) { }

}
```

But then how do I save the name? I would have to have another property for example `_name` that would be used to save the actual value

```
class Person {

  set name(newName) {

    // some actions
    return this._name;

  }

  set name(newName) {

    this._name = name;
    // some actions

  }

  constructor(name) {

    this._name = name;

  }

}
```

The problem is that `_name` can be accessed outside with `person._name`.

Is there a way to make it not accessible from outside?

---

I took inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5222319) (which doesn't use a getter and setter) and tried to enclose `_name` when defining the getter and setter. The following code doesn't work:

```
class Person {

    constructor(name) {

        var _name = name;
        Object.defineProperties(this, {
            "name": {
                 "get": () => { return _name; },
                 "set": () => { _name = name; }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: "*The problem is that `_name` can be accessed outside with `person._name`.*" - Is that really a problem? Every sensible developer will notice the leading underscore and by convention not use this property when the `.name` getter is available anyway that gets you the exact same value.

Comment: "*The following code doesn't work:*" - it does. What is the error you are getting, how are you using that `Person` class?

Comment: @Bergi: we all know that "doesn't work" tells us little.  But the code as described doesn't allow you to set the name.  A side-effect in that `set` call will still run, but the internal property won't change because it's missing the parameter, as NicholasTower pointed out.

Comment: @Bergi *Is that really a problem?*, I thought it was... Having both `_name` and `name` as properties seemed like an issue to me.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, thank you, I have removed my answer. I totally forgot that the initial goal was to use a setter to perform some actions when setting the value.

Comment: In your code, with Nicholas Tower's tweak, you will not have a `_name` property.  That will be captured in the closure.  This is as close as you're likely to get to private properties in JS until the new feature is added.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, I understand that the getter can return the enclosed value held by `_name`. However, I find it hard to understand how the Setter can redefine `_name`'s value. Are private properties actually planned as future features?

Comment: @Ivan: I believe there is at least one TC39 proposal for private properties.  I don't know what stage they're in or how likely they are to proceed.  As to how that variable is changeable, the constructor function creates a closure, and any functions inside that closure, such as `get name` and `set name` have access to the variables inside that closure, including `_name`.  They can both access and mutate it.  For more details, search for "javascript closure".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "set": () => { _name = name; }

You just have a small mistake here. Should be:

```
"set": (newName) => { _name = newName; }
```

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't expecting this kind of mistake to be the problem!